# Why is my calculator multiplying my answers by 3/3?

Tags: java

I put together a fraction calculator. It has a Fraction class with Fraction objects made up of an int numerator and int denominator. I made a bunch of methods that add, subtract, etc 2 fractions, and they all work fine on their own. However, after I made some changes to the input, it still gives me the right answer, but it multiplies the final answer by 3/3. Here is the main class:

```
    public class Main {

    public static int parseNum(String str) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/ *");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String string1 = str.substring(0, matcher.start());
            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(string1);
            return num1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public static int parseDem(String str) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/ *");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String string2 = str.substring(matcher.end());
            int dem1 = Integer.parseInt(string2);
            return dem1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Do you want to add, subtract, multiply, or divide?");
        String operator = in.next();
        System.out.println("Input fraction 1:");
        String str = in.next();


        System.out.println("Input fraction 2:");
        String str1 = in.next();

        Fraction first = new Fraction(parseNum(str), parseDem(str));
        Fraction second = new Fraction(parseNum(str1), parseDem(str1));

        if (operator.equals("add")) {
            first.add(second);
            System.out.println(first);
        } else if (operator.equals("subtract")) {
            first.subtract(second);
            System.out.println(first);
        } else if (operator.equals("multiply")) {
            first.multiply(second);
            System.out.println(first);
        } else if (operator.equals("divide")) {
            first.divide(second);
            System.out.println(first);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the Fraction class:

```
public class Fraction {
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    public Fraction(int numerator1, int denominator1){
        numerator = numerator1;
        denominator = denominator1;
    }

    public int getNumerator() {
        return numerator;
    }

    public int getDenominator() {
        return denominator;
    }

    public void add(Fraction other) {
        int newNumerator = (numerator * other.getDenominator()) + (denominator * other.getNumerator());
        numerator = newNumerator;
        int newDenominator = denominator * other.getDenominator();
        denominator = newDenominator;
    }

    public void subtract(Fraction other) {
        int newNumerator = (numerator * other.getDenominator()) - (denominator * other.getNumerator());
        numerator = newNumerator;
        int newDenominator = denominator * other.getDenominator();
        denominator = newDenominator;
    }

    public void multiply(Fraction other) {
        int newNumerator = numerator * other.getNumerator();
        numerator = newNumerator;
        int newDenominator = denominator * other.getDenominator();
        denominator = newDenominator;
    }

    public void divide(Fraction other) {
        int newNumerator = numerator * other.getDenominator();
        numerator = newNumerator;
        int newDenominator = denominator * other.getNumerator();
        denominator = newDenominator;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return numerator + "/" + denominator;
    }
}
```

Also, I know it's not very efficient, I'm working on that. Just wondering about the 3/3 thing at the moment. Also, I know it doesn't change the answer. I just mean that for example 2/3 becomes 6/9

Comment: 3/3 = 1. Multiplying by 1 does not change the answer. What?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. We need to see the `Fraction` class.

Comment: You don't normalize the fraction.